# Double-instantiating a select on an element garnish-0.1.min.js

Tags: assets

I am getting this error

```
Double-instantiating a select on an element garnish-0.1.min.js:18
```

and it is now stopping me adding files to an entry as will not display any files within an entry assets window.

Comment: This is worded as a bug report, not a question. You should email your bug reports directly to Pixel and Tonic (Assets' developers).

Comment: I see this error on mine and it has no impact on functionality.  If you'd like to email us, I'd be happy to have a look directly at your site and help troubleshoot. :)  support@pixelandtonic.com